SLAAC and SLAAC+DHCPv6 configuration using udhcp6
I am working on an embedded system and it uses udhcpc6 as its DHCPv6 client.
If I set an interface to 'dhcp' in the /etc/network/interfaces file, udhcp and udhcp6 automatically start.
I then connect my system on an OpenWRT router, with the following setup:
config dhcp 'lan'
        option interface 'lan'
...
        option dhcpv4 'server'
        option dhcpv6 'server'
        option ra 'server'
        option ra_slaac '1'
        list ra_flags '0'

Based on that setup, the router has a DHCPv4 and DHCPv6 running, but DHCPv6 should not be used for getting a DHCPv6 address (the M-flag in RA is not set).
However, my system, that runs udhcpc6, still gets a DHCPv6 address from the router. To confirm the expected functionality, a W10 host connected to the same openWRT router does not get a DHCPv6.
What is the best way to configure my system correctly, so that it works correctly both for SLAAC only, and for SLAAC+DHCPv6? Is there a way to only run udhcpc6 if the received RA message has the M-flag set? Is there an easier approach?
